# Performance of int vs unsigned long long for prime number testing in C

Tags: c

Why does it take longer to do an operation on an `unsigned long long` than on an `int`?

`I've` done several tests using a function to find the nth prime number using exactly the same code, I don't need to provide the code, you could put it simply as: why does an `int` / `2` take less time than an `unsigned long long` / `2`?

I know the `/ 2` implies a cast to `unsigned long long`.

Here is the code:

```
int isPrime(int number) {
    if (number < 2) return 0;
    if (number == 2) return 1;
    if (number == 3) return 1;
    if (number == 5) return 1;
    if (!(number % 2)) return 0;
    if (!(number % 3)) return 0;
    if (!(number % 5)) return 0;
    if (number < 7 * 7) return 1;
    int step[] = { 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31 };
    int sentry = (int)sqrt((double)number);
    for (int r = 0; r < sentry; r += 30)
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
            if (!(number % (r + step[i])))
                return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Are you perhaps running this on a 32-bit processor?

Comment: A processor, which can't handle arithmetics on a 64-bit value natively, will have to split it to several commands. And even if it only uses one command, it can take more cycles (microcode instructions, pipelining). On a current 64-bit intel processor it shouldn't be slower, however.

Comment: thanks for your reply, no, 64 bit processor, this is an issue if you do the division on 1000000 which is well within 32 bit

Comment: @ctx this is the root of the problem i fear, but its a 64 bit processor

Comment: @brundle56uk: The size of the actual number doesn't really matter, the main issue is if your number is too big to fit in one register. But this isn't a problem if everything is 64-bit. Did you make sure your executable is also a 64-bit one? Some compilers might default to 32-bit executables.

Comment: What's the difference if you use `2ULL`?  BTW it's easiest if you can demo this and show the exact code.

Comment: What tools or commands did you use to compile and run this?

Comment: The underlying circuit complexity for 64 bits vs. 32 is more complex and should take more (barely noticable) clock cycles, but if it is noticable, I would imagine that you are compiling it as a 32bit executable which produces significantly different code for a 64 bit multiply (several instructions vs 1, in order to handle overflow and carry between 32bit registers) ... check your binary to find out (on Unix/Linux/Mac you can use file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` and `unsigned long long` most likely have a different size. Arithmetic operations on integers of different sizes may be implemented more or less efficiently depending on the CPU architecture and the compiler settings.

Without seeing any code, it is very difficult to determine which operation is likely to cause the difference in performance that you describe.  Dividing by 2 may actually more efficient on an `unsigned long long`, where it can always be implemented as a single bitshift by 1 position to the right, than on an `int` where an adjustment is required if the value is not known to be positive.

Other operations may take much longer on 64 bit values than on 32 bit values, such as multiplications and divisions or modulo operations, which are probably the bottleneck in your implementation.

Your code uses many divisions and modulo operations, these are most costly on `unsigned long long` than on `int` values, especially for the last loop where the divisions are not compiled as multiplications.

Note that you can slightly improve efficiency by defining `step` this way:

```
static const int step[] = { 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31 };
```

Note also that is may not be very efficient to mix floating point operations and integer arithmetic, and it may actually be incorrect to stop at `sqrt((double)number)` if number is a large `unsigned long long` because of the loss of precision converting a 64 bit integer to a 53 bit floating point mantissa.

Here is an alternative with fewer tests:

```
typedef unsigned long long int num_t;

#define PBITS64  ((1<<2) | (1<<3) | (1<<5) | (1<<7) | (1<<11) | (1<<13) | \
                  (1ULL<<17) | (1ULL<<19) | (1ULL<<23) | (1ULL<<29) | \
                  (1ULL<<31) | (1ULL<<37) | (1ULL<<41) | (1ULL<<43) | \
                  (1ULL<<47) | (1ULL<<53) | (1ULL<<59) | (1ULL<<61)
#define REMBITS30  ((1<<1) | (1<<7) | (1<<11) | (1<<13) | \
                    (1UL<<17) | (1UL<<19) | (1UL<<23) | (1UL<<29))

int isPrime(num_t number) {
    /* test all numbers below 64 */
    if (number < 64) return (PBITS64 >> number) & 1;
    /* test all multiples of 2, 3 and 5 */
    if (!((REMBITS30 >> (number % 30)) & 1)) return 0;
    static unsigned int const step[] = { 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31 };
    for (num_t r = 0; r * r < number - 16; r += 30) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
            if (!(number % (r + step[i])))
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This method is much faster for smaller numbers and multiples of 2 3 and 5, it works for all `unsigned long long`.

Comment: THIS is the answer ThankYou chqelie

Comment: the above method works upto 18446744073709551600 and can be adjusted for all values upto ULLONG_MAX, see updated answer.

Comment: You can use the Miller-Rabin test as explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test

Comment: this code gives 83 as a non prime which is obviously wrong, the code didn't compile, so i had to add a couple of brackets.  chqlie, could you reviews this please as I'm interested in this solution

Comment: @brundle56uk: excellent catch! There were 3 typos in the posted answer: a missing `)`, a redundant `(1<<37)` and a fatal `(1UL<23)` instead of `(1UL<<23)`. Shame on me!

Comment: thank you very much, that now gives the correct results, I'm running a load of speed tests on my little Raspberry Pi cluster, it already runs a second faster at 1million primes, will report back

Comment: This is the fastest algo

Answer (score 0):

This can't be answered without specifics of

1. The implementation (e.g. what compiler you are using)
2. The hardware you are running on
3. The code in question

They are likely to be the same on a 64 bit system (but not necessarily). On a 32 or 16 bit system, an `int` is likely to be faster. But of course, this depends on the implementation. The only truly accurate answer will be obtained from profiling.

Comment: gcc complier using gcc -wall -lm -std-c99   behaves the same on all hardware, code given above

Comment: You can't expect it to behave the same on all hardware, to do so is to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how code is executed on a computer

Answer (score 0):

If I take your `isPrime()` implementation and build it w/default optimizations using clang 3.7.0 for x86_64 linux, I get significantly different output when I make `number` an int vs an `unsigned long long`.

```
#include <math.h>

#ifdef USE_INT
typedef int NUM_TYPE;
#else
typedef unsigned long long NUM_TYPE ;
#endif

int isPrime(NUM_TYPE number)
{

    if (number < 2) return 0;
    if (number == 2) return 1;
    if (number == 3) return 1;
    if (number == 5) return 1;
    if (!(number % 2)) return 0;
    if (!(number % 3)) return 0;
    if (!(number % 5)) return 0;
    if (number < 7*7) return 1;
    int step[] = {7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31};
    int sentry = (NUM_TYPE)sqrt((double)number);
    for(int r = 0; r < sentry; r += 30)
            for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
                if (!(number % (r+step[i])))
                    return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

One of the more significant differences in the number of instructions come from this line:

```
int sentry = (NUM_TYPE)sqrt((double)number);
```

Also, many of the `cmpq` become `cmpl` when `NUM_TYPE` is `int`.

Here's the disassembly diff.  `NUM_TYPE` as `int` is on the right.

```
$ sdiff -t prime.S prime_int.S 

prime.o:     file format elf64-x86-64                           |  prime_int.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:                                      Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <isPrime>:                                        0000000000000000 <isPrime>:
#else                                                              #else
typedef unsigned long long NUM_TYPE ;                              typedef unsigned long long NUM_TYPE ;
#endif                                                             #endif

int isPrime(NUM_TYPE number)                                       int isPrime(NUM_TYPE number)
{                                                                  {
   0:   55                      push   %rbp                           0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp                      1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   48 83 ec 50             sub    $0x50,%rsp                     4:   48 83 ec 50             sub    $0x50,%rsp
   8:   48 89 7d f0             mov    %rdi,-0x10(%rbp)         |     8:   89 7d f8                mov    %edi,-0x8(%rbp)

        if (number < 2) return 0;                                          if (number < 2) return 0;
   c:   48 83 7d f0 02          cmpq   $0x2,-0x10(%rbp)         |     b:   83 7d f8 02             cmpl   $0x2,-0x8(%rbp)
  11:   0f 83 0c 00 00 00       jae    23 <isPrime+0x23>        |     f:   0f 8d 0c 00 00 00       jge    21 <isPrime+0x21>
  17:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)          |    15:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
  1e:   e9 c1 01 00 00          jmpq   1e4 <isPrime+0x1e4>      |    1c:   e9 88 01 00 00          jmpq   1a9 <isPrime+0x1a9>
        if (number == 2) return 1;                                         if (number == 2) return 1;
  23:   48 83 7d f0 02          cmpq   $0x2,-0x10(%rbp)         |    21:   83 7d f8 02             cmpl   $0x2,-0x8(%rbp)
  28:   0f 85 0c 00 00 00       jne    3a <isPrime+0x3a>        |    25:   0f 85 0c 00 00 00       jne    37 <isPrime+0x37>
  2e:   c7 45 fc 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)          |    2b:   c7 45 fc 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
  35:   e9 aa 01 00 00          jmpq   1e4 <isPrime+0x1e4>      |    32:   e9 72 01 00 00          jmpq   1a9 <isPrime+0x1a9>
        if (number == 3) return 1;                                         if (number == 3) return 1;
  3a:   48 83 7d f0 03          cmpq   $0x3,-0x10(%rbp)         |    37:   83 7d f8 03             cmpl   $0x3,-0x8(%rbp)
  3f:   0f 85 0c 00 00 00       jne    51 <isPrime+0x51>        |    3b:   0f 85 0c 00 00 00       jne    4d <isPrime+0x4d>
  45:   c7 45 fc 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)          |    41:   c7 45 fc 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
  4c:   e9 93 01 00 00          jmpq   1e4 <isPrime+0x1e4>      |    48:   e9 5c 01 00 00          jmpq   1a9 <isPrime+0x1a9>
        if (number == 5) return 1;                                         if (number == 5) return 1;
  51:   48 83 7d f0 05          cmpq   $0x5,-0x10(%rbp)         |    4d:   83 7d f8 05             cmpl   $0x5,-0x8(%rbp)
  56:   0f 85 0c 00 00 00       jne    68 <isPrime+0x68>        |    51:   0f 85 0c 00 00 00       jne    63 <isPrime+0x63>
  5c:   c7 45 fc 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)          |    57:   c7 45 fc 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
  63:   e9 7c 01 00 00          jmpq   1e4 <isPrime+0x1e4>      |    5e:   e9 46 01 00 00          jmpq   1a9 <isPrime+0x1a9>
                                                                >    63:   b8 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%eax
        if (!(number % 2)) return 0;                                       if (!(number % 2)) return 0;
  68:   48 8b 45 f0             mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax         |    68:   8b 4d f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%ecx
  6c:   48 83 e0 01             and    $0x1,%rax                |    6b:   89 45 c0                mov    %eax,-0x40(%rbp)
  70:   48 83 f8 00             cmp    $0x0,%rax                |    6e:   89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
  74:   0f 85 0c 00 00 00       jne    86 <isPrime+0x86>        |    70:   99                      cltd   
  7a:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)          |    71:   8b 4d c0                mov    -0x40(%rbp),%ecx
  81:   e9 5e 01 00 00          jmpq   1e4 <isPrime+0x1e4>      |    74:   f7 f9                   idiv   %ecx
  86:   b8 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%eax                |    76:   83 fa 00                cmp    $0x0,%edx
  8b:   89 c1                   mov    %eax,%ecx                |    79:   0f 85 0c 00 00 00       jne    8b <isPrime+0x8b>
                                                                >    7f:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
                                                                >    86:   e9 1e 01 00 00          jmpq   1a9 <isPrime+0x1a9>
                                                                >    8b:   b8 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%eax
        if (!(number % 3)) return 0;                                       if (!(number % 3)) return 0;
  8d:   48 8b 45 f0             mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax         |    90:   8b 4d f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%ecx
  91:   31 d2                   xor    %edx,%edx                |    93:   89 45 bc                mov    %eax,-0x44(%rbp)
  93:   48 f7 f1                div    %rcx                     |    96:   89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
  96:   48 83 fa 00             cmp    $0x0,%rdx                |    98:   99                      cltd   
  9a:   0f 85 0c 00 00 00       jne    ac <isPrime+0xac>        |    99:   8b 4d bc                mov    -0x44(%rbp),%ecx
  a0:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)          |    9c:   f7 f9                   idiv   %ecx
  a7:   e9 38 01 00 00          jmpq   1e4 <isPrime+0x1e4>      |    9e:   83 fa 00                cmp    $0x0,%edx
  ac:   b8 05 00 00 00          mov    $0x5,%eax                |    a1:   0f 85 0c 00 00 00       jne    b3 <isPrime+0xb3>
  b1:   89 c1                   mov    %eax,%ecx                |    a7:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
                                                                >    ae:   e9 f6 00 00 00          jmpq   1a9 <isPrime+0x1a9>
                                                                >    b3:   b8 05 00 00 00          mov    $0x5,%eax
        if (!(number % 5)) return 0;                                       if (!(number % 5)) return 0;
  b3:   48 8b 45 f0             mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax         |    b8:   8b 4d f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%ecx
  b7:   31 d2                   xor    %edx,%edx                |    bb:   89 45 b8                mov    %eax,-0x48(%rbp)
  b9:   48 f7 f1                div    %rcx                     |    be:   89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
  bc:   48 83 fa 00             cmp    $0x0,%rdx                |    c0:   99                      cltd   
  c0:   0f 85 0c 00 00 00       jne    d2 <isPrime+0xd2>        |    c1:   8b 4d b8                mov    -0x48(%rbp),%ecx
  c6:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)          |    c4:   f7 f9                   idiv   %ecx
  cd:   e9 12 01 00 00          jmpq   1e4 <isPrime+0x1e4>      |    c6:   83 fa 00                cmp    $0x0,%edx
                                                                >    c9:   0f 85 0c 00 00 00       jne    db <isPrime+0xdb>
                                                                >    cf:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
                                                                >    d6:   e9 ce 00 00 00          jmpq   1a9 <isPrime+0x1a9>
        if (number < 7*7) return 1;                                        if (number < 7*7) return 1;
  d2:   48 83 7d f0 31          cmpq   $0x31,-0x10(%rbp)        |    db:   83 7d f8 31             cmpl   $0x31,-0x8(%rbp)
  d7:   0f 83 0c 00 00 00       jae    e9 <isPrime+0xe9>        |    df:   0f 8d 0c 00 00 00       jge    f1 <isPrime+0xf1>
  dd:   c7 45 fc 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)          |    e5:   c7 45 fc 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
  e4:   e9 fb 00 00 00          jmpq   1e4 <isPrime+0x1e4>      |    ec:   e9 b8 00 00 00          jmpq   1a9 <isPrime+0x1a9>
        int step[] = {7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31};                             int step[] = {7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31};
  e9:   0f 28 05 00 00 00 00    movaps 0x0(%rip),%xmm0        # |    f1:   48 8b 04 25 00 00 00    mov    0x0,%rax
  f0:   0f 29 45 e0             movaps %xmm0,-0x20(%rbp)        |    f8:   00 
  f4:   0f 28 05 00 00 00 00    movaps 0x0(%rip),%xmm0        # |    f9:   48 89 45 d0             mov    %rax,-0x30(%rbp)
  fb:   0f 29 45 d0             movaps %xmm0,-0x30(%rbp)        |    fd:   48 8b 04 25 00 00 00    mov    0x0,%rax
                                                                >   104:   00 
                                                                >   105:   48 89 45 d8             mov    %rax,-0x28(%rbp)
                                                                >   109:   48 8b 04 25 00 00 00    mov    0x0,%rax
                                                                >   110:   00 
                                                                >   111:   48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
                                                                >   115:   48 8b 04 25 00 00 00    mov    0x0,%rax
                                                                >   11c:   00 
                                                                >   11d:   48 89 45 e8             mov    %rax,-0x18(%rbp)
        int sentry = (NUM_TYPE)sqrt((double)number);                       int sentry = (NUM_TYPE)sqrt((double)number);
  ff:   0f 28 05 00 00 00 00    movaps 0x0(%rip),%xmm0        # |   121:   f2 0f 2a 45 f8          cvtsi2sdl -0x8(%rbp),%xmm0
 106:   f3 0f 7e 4d f0          movq   -0x10(%rbp),%xmm1        |   126:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  12b <isPrime+0x12b>
 10b:   66 0f 62 c8             punpckldq %xmm0,%xmm1           |   12b:   f2 0f 2c c8             cvttsd2si %xmm0,%ecx
 10f:   66 0f 28 05 00 00 00    movapd 0x0(%rip),%xmm0        # |   12f:   89 4d cc                mov    %ecx,-0x34(%rbp)
 116:   00                                                      <
 117:   66 0f 5c c8             subpd  %xmm0,%xmm1              <
 11b:   66 0f 70 c1 4e          pshufd $0x4e,%xmm1,%xmm0        <
 120:   66 0f 58 c1             addpd  %xmm1,%xmm0              <
 124:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  129 <isPrime+0x129>      <
 129:   f2 0f 10 0d 00 00 00    movsd  0x0(%rip),%xmm1        # <
 130:   00                                                      <
 131:   0f 28 d0                movaps %xmm0,%xmm2              <
 134:   f2 0f 5c d1             subsd  %xmm1,%xmm2              <
 138:   f2 48 0f 2c c2          cvttsd2si %xmm2,%rax            <
 13d:   48 b9 00 00 00 00 00    movabs $0x8000000000000000,%rcx <
 144:   00 00 80                                                <
 147:   48 31 c8                xor    %rcx,%rax                <
 14a:   f2 48 0f 2c c8          cvttsd2si %xmm0,%rcx            <
 14f:   66 0f 2e c1             ucomisd %xmm1,%xmm0             <
 153:   48 0f 42 c1             cmovb  %rcx,%rax                <
 157:   89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx                <
 159:   89 55 cc                mov    %edx,-0x34(%rbp)         <
        for(int r = 0; r < sentry; r += 30)                                for(int r = 0; r < sentry; r += 30)
 15c:   c7 45 c8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x38(%rbp)         |   132:   c7 45 c8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x38(%rbp)
 163:   8b 45 c8                mov    -0x38(%rbp),%eax         |   139:   8b 45 c8                mov    -0x38(%rbp),%eax
 166:   3b 45 cc                cmp    -0x34(%rbp),%eax         |   13c:   3b 45 cc                cmp    -0x34(%rbp),%eax
 169:   0f 8d 6e 00 00 00       jge    1dd <isPrime+0x1dd>      |   13f:   0f 8d 5d 00 00 00       jge    1a2 <isPrime+0x1a2>
            for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)                                         for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
 16f:   c7 45 c4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x3c(%rbp)         |   145:   c7 45 c4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x3c(%rbp)
 176:   83 7d c4 08             cmpl   $0x8,-0x3c(%rbp)         |   14c:   83 7d c4 08             cmpl   $0x8,-0x3c(%rbp)
 17a:   0f 8d 4a 00 00 00       jge    1ca <isPrime+0x1ca>      |   150:   0f 8d 39 00 00 00       jge    18f <isPrime+0x18f>
                if (!(number % (r+step[i])))                                       if (!(number % (r+step[i])))
 180:   48 8b 45 f0             mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax         |   156:   8b 45 f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
 184:   8b 4d c8                mov    -0x38(%rbp),%ecx         |   159:   8b 4d c8                mov    -0x38(%rbp),%ecx
 187:   48 63 55 c4             movslq -0x3c(%rbp),%rdx         |   15c:   48 63 55 c4             movslq -0x3c(%rbp),%rdx
 18b:   03 4c 95 d0             add    -0x30(%rbp,%rdx,4),%ecx  |   160:   03 4c 95 d0             add    -0x30(%rbp,%rdx,4),%ecx
 18f:   48 63 d1                movslq %ecx,%rdx                |   164:   99                      cltd   
 192:   31 c9                   xor    %ecx,%ecx                |   165:   f7 f9                   idiv   %ecx
 194:   48 89 55 b8             mov    %rdx,-0x48(%rbp)         |   167:   83 fa 00                cmp    $0x0,%edx
 198:   89 ca                   mov    %ecx,%edx                |   16a:   0f 85 0c 00 00 00       jne    17c <isPrime+0x17c>
 19a:   48 8b 75 b8             mov    -0x48(%rbp),%rsi         <
 19e:   48 f7 f6                div    %rsi                     <
 1a1:   48 83 fa 00             cmp    $0x0,%rdx                <
 1a5:   0f 85 0c 00 00 00       jne    1b7 <isPrime+0x1b7>      <
                    return 0;                                                          return 0;
 1ab:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)          |   170:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
 1b2:   e9 2d 00 00 00          jmpq   1e4 <isPrime+0x1e4>      |   177:   e9 2d 00 00 00          jmpq   1a9 <isPrime+0x1a9>
        if (number < 7*7) return 1;                                        if (number < 7*7) return 1;
        int step[] = {7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31};                             int step[] = {7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31};
        int sentry = (NUM_TYPE)sqrt((double)number);                       int sentry = (NUM_TYPE)sqrt((double)number);
        for(int r = 0; r < sentry; r += 30)                                for(int r = 0; r < sentry; r += 30)
            for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)                                         for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
                if (!(number % (r+step[i])))                                       if (!(number % (r+step[i])))
 1b7:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   1bc <isPrime+0x1bc>      |   17c:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   181 <isPrime+0x181>
        if (!(number % 5)) return 0;                                       if (!(number % 5)) return 0;
        if (number < 7*7) return 1;                                        if (number < 7*7) return 1;
        int step[] = {7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31};                             int step[] = {7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31};
        int sentry = (NUM_TYPE)sqrt((double)number);                       int sentry = (NUM_TYPE)sqrt((double)number);
        for(int r = 0; r < sentry; r += 30)                                for(int r = 0; r < sentry; r += 30)
            for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)                                         for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
 1bc:   8b 45 c4                mov    -0x3c(%rbp),%eax         |   181:   8b 45 c4                mov    -0x3c(%rbp),%eax
 1bf:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax                |   184:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
 1c2:   89 45 c4                mov    %eax,-0x3c(%rbp)         |   187:   89 45 c4                mov    %eax,-0x3c(%rbp)
 1c5:   e9 ac ff ff ff          jmpq   176 <isPrime+0x176>      |   18a:   e9 bd ff ff ff          jmpq   14c <isPrime+0x14c>
                if (!(number % (r+step[i])))                                       if (!(number % (r+step[i])))
                    return 0;                                                          return 0;
 1ca:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   1cf <isPrime+0x1cf>      |   18f:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   194 <isPrime+0x194>
        if (!(number % 3)) return 0;                                       if (!(number % 3)) return 0;
        if (!(number % 5)) return 0;                                       if (!(number % 5)) return 0;
        if (number < 7*7) return 1;                                        if (number < 7*7) return 1;
        int step[] = {7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31};                             int step[] = {7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31};
        int sentry = (NUM_TYPE)sqrt((double)number);                       int sentry = (NUM_TYPE)sqrt((double)number);
        for(int r = 0; r < sentry; r += 30)                                for(int r = 0; r < sentry; r += 30)
 1cf:   8b 45 c8                mov    -0x38(%rbp),%eax         |   194:   8b 45 c8                mov    -0x38(%rbp),%eax
 1d2:   83 c0 1e                add    $0x1e,%eax               |   197:   83 c0 1e                add    $0x1e,%eax
 1d5:   89 45 c8                mov    %eax,-0x38(%rbp)         |   19a:   89 45 c8                mov    %eax,-0x38(%rbp)
 1d8:   e9 86 ff ff ff          jmpq   163 <isPrime+0x163>      |   19d:   e9 97 ff ff ff          jmpq   139 <isPrime+0x139>
            for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)                                         for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
                if (!(number % (r+step[i])))                                       if (!(number % (r+step[i])))
                    return 0;                                                          return 0;
        return 1;                                                          return 1;
 1dd:   c7 45 fc 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)          |   1a2:   c7 45 fc 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
}                                                                  }
 1e4:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax          |   1a9:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
 1e7:   48 83 c4 50             add    $0x50,%rsp               |   1ac:   48 83 c4 50             add    $0x50,%rsp
 1eb:   5d                      pop    %rbp                     |   1b0:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 1ec:   c3                      retq                            |   1b1:   c3                      retq
```

Comment: yeah iwas wondering about that, i'm sure i've tried it but could you run that again and replace that line with int sentry = sqrt(number)/2+1;
: